# From javascript function execution getting wrong calculation

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript function to execute my string value, I have input like,

"0110 + 0123" = 155 ( I am getting )

But actually output was "233"

```
var total = "0110 + 0123";
total = ( new Function( 'return ' +  memberData) )();
console.log(total);
```

How to hide or remove zero while calculating value.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning a number with `0` makes it an octal number. 
Your result is `0233` octal which is `155` decimal.

Test: Type `233` in the JavaScript console of your favorite browser. It will answer `233`. Type `0233` and it will answer `155`.

Comment: The result is actually `155` - it's never interpreted as octal. The two operands would be immediately translated to decimal - `0110` -> `72` and `0123` -> `83`, so you get the result of `72 + 83`. Or to be more precise, the literal will be translated to the IEEE 754 numeric underneath. Point is, the calculation is not done in octal.

Comment: yes, the calculation will not be done in octal nor will it be done in decimal. It just does not matter in which base the calculation will be done. It is only about converting the external representation to internal data type and vice versa. This is not the crucial point in my answer. I just did not say in which representation the calculation has been done.

Comment: Yes i agree @Donat, then how to archive this calculation. My input will be in string "0110 + 0123 - 0122 * 0122" it may like this. i am passing this string to evaluate output for above string....

Answer (score 0):

```
var ac = parseInt("0110", 10);
var ad = parseInt("0123", 10);
var total = ac + ad;
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Hi @Abhay singh my input will in string 

"0110 + 0123 - 0122 * 0122" it may like this. i am passing this string to evaluate output for above string....